# Como usar o valor de um select com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select, formulário

Gostaria de saber como faço para usar o índice de um select, por exemplo eu tenho o select abaixo

```js
function verificartime() {
  let time = window.document.getElementsByName("time")
  let restime = window.document.getElementById("restime")

  // se o time selecionado for o indice[1] então restime.innerHTML="Palmeiras"
  // se o time selecionado for o indice[2] então restime.innerHTML="Corinthians" e assim por diante


}
```

```html
<select name="time">
  <option>Selecione seu time</option>
  <option value="palmeiras">Palmeiras</option>
  <option value="corinthians">Corinthians</option>
  <option value="saopaulo">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="santos">Santos</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Time" onclick="verificartime()">
<div id="restime">
  Aqui vai o resultado do select
</div>
```

Gostaria de ao selecionar qualquer time que retornasse o valor na div

OBS: Estou tentando diversas formas procurando na net mas nao encontro uma maneira de executar isso,sou iniciante

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas que poderia fazer é: retirar o *window*, deixar apenas o *document* que já vai funcionar. Trocar o *getElementsByName* e usar o *getElementById* mesmo, e mudar a propriedade *name* lá no *select* para *id* também. Depois só usar o *innerHTML* na *div* que você recuperou com o *getElementById*. Veja se isso resolve:

```js
function verificartime() {
  let time = document.getElementById("time")
  let restime = document.getElementById("restime")

  /*aqui você consegue acessar o text do option, se quiser o value dele,
  só usar time.value; */
  var timeSelecionado = time.options[time.selectedIndex].text;
  
  restime.innerHTML = timeSelecionado;
}
```

```html
<select id="time">
  <option>Selecione seu time</option>
  <option value="palmeiras">Palmeiras</option>
  <option value="corinthians">Corinthians</option>
  <option value="saopaulo">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="santos">Santos</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Time" onclick="verificartime()">
<div id="restime">
  Aqui vai o resultado do select
</div>
```